# How to check treeView node duplicate from database C#, WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, duplicates, nodes

I have this code to prevent duplicates in nodes of treeView but its not working. Any error in my code?

```
     DataTable dt= new DataTable();
     OleDbDataAdapter sda= new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblName", conn);
     sdas.Fill(dt);  

for (int x = 0; x < dt.Rows.Count; x++)
{         
     if (!treeView1.Nodes.ContainsKey(dt.Rows[x]["Name"].ToString()))
          treeView1.Nodes.Add(dt.Rows[x]["Name"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: Perform the distinct in the database query

Comment: @MitchWheat in database? how?

Comment: @ViFer: try to google "SQL SELECT DISTINCT", there'll be many interesting things in search results.

Comment: try this article .. http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/12/13/select-distinct-order-by-error.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You also need specify the key parameter.

```cs
 if (!treeView1.Nodes.ContainsKey(dt.Rows[x]["Name"].ToString()))
      treeView1.Nodes.Add(dt.Rows[x]["Name"].ToString(), dt.Rows[x]["Name"].ToString());
```

You used `Add` method with one parameter, that will not set Name property (Name is key).

[Add(string text)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/esz34cwb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

[Add(string key, string text)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/57aa8e09%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)